# How do I use an object reference as an argument if it is instantiated after the class taking the argument?

Tags: java, class, object, constructor, arguments

So I have this code:

```
package com.erikbalen.game.rpg;
import com.erikbalen.platform.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class World extends Engine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

    Gui display = new Gui(/*takes a Player argument so i can get certain variables*/);
    display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    display.setSize(300,220);
    display.setVisible(true);

    Player player1 = new Dps("ebalen", display);
    Player player2 = new Healer("frankypanky", display);

    }

}

package com.erikbalen.game.rpg;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -384241835772507459L;
    private JLabel playerInfo;
    private JTextField textField;
    private final static String newline = "\n";
    private JTextArea feed;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private Player player;

    public Gui(Player currentPlayer) {
        super("Erik's RPG");
        this.player = currentPlayer;
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        playerInfo = new JLabel("<html>Health = " + currentPlayer.getHealth() + " | " + "Mana = " + currentPlayer.getMana() + "</html>");

        playerInfo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(currentPlayer.getName()));

        textField = new JTextField(20);

        textField.addActionListener(this);

        feed = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(feed);
        feed.setEditable(false);

        add(playerInfo);
        add(feed);
        add(textField);
        add(scrollPane);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent textBox) {
         String text = textField.getText();
         this.player.chat(text);

    }

    public void printText(String text) {
        feed.append(text + "\n");
        feed.setCaretPosition(feed.getDocument().getLength());
    }

}
```

My problem is that class Gui takes a Player as an argument and Player takes Gui as an argument. How do I let both objects take each other as arguments? Feel free to tell me if my code is inefficient.

Comment: Why would `Gui` take a `Player` as a constructor argument? I think this is probably bad design. Please show your `Gui` code.

Comment: Because Gui displays some of the player's information and I didn't know how else for it to access the players variables.

Comment: You can make `setPlayer` method instead of using constructor parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, ideally you should try to break the circular dependency, but otherwise, you could:

- Create the GUI, create the players by passing in the GUI, then add the players to the GUI
- Create the players, create the GUI by passing in the players, then set the GUI for the players
- Create the GUI within the player constructor:

  ```
  Player(String name)
  {
      GUI gui = new GUi(this);
      ...
  }
  ```

All of these are non-ideal:

- You may well want your classes to be immutable, which makes the first two options nasty
- Publishing the `this` reference before your constructor has finished executing has various issues, both in terms of thread safety and the memory model, as well as potentially allowing the `GUI` constructor to call back to the `Player` object before it's fully initialized.

This goes back to "try to break the dependency" - but if that's *really* impossible, I would *probably* favour the first option, without knowing anything else. It makes sense to be able to add players to a game - it makes less sense to set the GUI for a player after the fact, IMO.

Comment: +1, I would emphasise more on *try to break dependency*. I wouldn't want a `StackOverflowError` to occur (sarcasm). Besides, debugging a circular depency is not a simple eye-opener without breaking few teeth and bones.

Comment: Could you explain maybe how I would break the dependency?

Comment: @ebalen: It's hard to say without knowing why there's a circular dependency. It seems very odd for the GUI constructor to take a *single* Player as the "current" one. Have you considered a setCurrentPlayer method which is called each time the current player changes?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the `Gui` class methods for updating what is displayed to the user/users. Make the directing code (`main()` for example) responsible for updating the `Gui` with the right information as events happen.

Neither `Gui` nor `Player` should have to take each other as constructor arguments - `Gui` should only be responsible for displaying information it is told to, and `Player` should only be a logical representation of a game piece. Event-driven functionality should be reserved for the directing code.

Answer (score 1):

Your stuck in what we call a circular dependency. This is almost everytime the result of a bad design.

There are still solutions, but there are not really pretty. For an elegant way, you should rethink your design.
Does the GUI really need the player ? Maybe you could create a method to set the player later on. If it's not possible, you could also create a setter in the player. You won't be able to set both at construction time.